# How to pretty print object representation in IPython

Tags: ipython

IPython outputs list representation in a pretty way by default:

```
In [1]: test_list
Out[1]: [<object_1>,
         <object_2>,
         <object_3>]
```

I have object like:

```
class TestObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._list = [<object_1>, <object_2>, <object_3>]

    def __repr__(self):
        return self._list.__repr__()

test_object = Test()
```

And IPython representation of this is:

```
In [2]: test_list
Out[2]: [<object_1>, <object_2>, <object_3>]
```

Is there a way to get list's way of the representation for my object?

Comment: What are you expecting? do you want object_i to be pretty? If so you need to override the __repr__ of those objects.

Comment: Your class `repr` is using the regular list `repr`, not `Ipython's`.  A simple fix is to change your `repr` to include `\n`.

Comment: @kabanus: I've already made object's repr pretty, what I expect is to print each object in a new line (the same way as IPython does for normal list).

Comment: @hpaulj: Thanks for the idea, I will do it manually. I just thought if there is a way to let the IPython do it.

Comment: What `Ipython` gets from your `repr` is a string, not a list; so it doesn't do anything further to make it pretty.

Comment: You can get the pretty-printed format of a list (or any object) by calling `IPython.lib.pretty.pretty(my_list)`.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasK, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the pretty-printed repr of a list, or any object, call:

```
from IPython.lib.pretty import pretty
pretty(obj)
```

If you want your object to have a pretty repr separate from its normal repr (e.g. so it doesn't need IPython to `repr()` it), you can define a [`_repr_pretty_(self, p, cycle)`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.lib.pretty.html#extending) method. The `cycle` parameter will be true if the representation recurses - e.g. if you put a container inside itself.