# Making an object's pretty-print representation different if it appears at top-level compared to nested

Tags: python, ipython

In IPython, it is possible to make an object have a custom pretty-print representation as explained in [How to pretty print object representation in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40193479/5267751) :

```py
class MyObject:
    def _repr_pretty_(self, p, cycle):
        p.text("<MyObject: object content>")
```

Then in the shell, the pretty-printed output will be:

```py
In [5]: MyObject()
Out[5]: <MyObject: object content>
```

However, if multiple `MyObject()` objects appear in a list/dictionary etc., then it may get long.

```
In [6]: [MyObject(), MyObject()]
Out[6]: [<MyObject: object content>, <MyObject: object content>]
```

I want to do the following:

- If `MyObject()` appears at top level, the long description as above appears.
- If it appears nested, **the representation should be replaced with `<MyObject: ...>`**.

My reasoning: having too much content will clutter the user's view, and if the user wants to see what is the detail inside, they can simply write `list[0]`.

How can I implement that in IPython shell? Or, is there any better approach to this problem?

Comment: FWIW, if you used a graphical frontend, you could use `_repr_html_` or another method like that. They only work at the top level AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define [`_ipython_display_()`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html#MyObject._ipython_display_).

```
class MyObject:
    def _ipython_display_(self):
        print("<MyObject: object content>")

    def _repr_pretty_(self, p, cycle):
        p.text("<MyObject: ...>")
```

```
In [20]: MyObject()
Out[20]: <MyObject: object content>

In [21]: [MyObject(), MyObject()]
Out[21]: [<MyObject: ...>, <MyObject: ...>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way I can find is to access `p.group_stack`. Unfortunately, `group_stack` is completely undocumented as far as I can tell, so use it at your own risk.

```py
class MyObject:
    def _repr_pretty_(self, p, cycle):
        if len(p.group_stack)>2:
            p.text("<MyObject: ...>")
        else:
            p.text("<MyObject: object content>")
```

The output is as expected.

```py
In [2]: MyObject()
Out[2]: <MyObject: object content>

In [3]: [MyObject(), MyObject()]
Out[3]: [<MyObject: ...>, <MyObject: ...>]
```